# Writing decorator function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

Apologies if it is repetitive but I am struggling to find a solution with this. I am trying to write a decorator function below.

```
  def search_func(sheetname):
    def insider(function):
        def wraper(*args, **kwargs):
            file = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\khisr\OneDrive\Documents\TestPage.xlsx")
            currnet_sheet = file[sheetname]
            function(currnet_sheet)
        return wraper
    return insider         


@search_func('Passwords')
def Longin(self, currnet_sheet):
    Name = self.User_name.get() + str(self.Password.get())
    for i in range(1,current_sheet.max_row +1):
       for j in range(1,current_sheet.max_column+1):
           if current_sheet.cell(i,j).value == Name:
```

The function is called with a button;

```
self.Button = tk.Button(self.Main_frame, text='Enter', bg = 'green', command = self.Longin)
```

I get an error

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/khisr/OneDrive/Documents/PythonProjects/Dubai_Project/login.py", line 71, in wraper
    function(currnet_sheet)
TypeError: Longin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'currnet_sheet"
```

Any help or commend is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Your decorator is fine . The issue is with whatever is calling the `Longin` method. Probably because `tk.Button` expects what you pass to be function not a method (methods require `self`). If you want `Longin` to be part of a class then try turning it into a `@staticmethod`.

Comment: Thanks, Can you elaborate on the @staticmethod? At the moment, the @search_func('Passwords') pass the 'Paswords' which is the page, I want the def search_func(sheetname) function to open. How can I pass the page name that needs to be opened using the @staticmethod?

Comment: Not the error but you probably want to return in your decorator: `return function(currnet_sheet)`, otherwise if you decorate a method/function that returns something the decorator will consume it.

Comment: Sorry staticmethod wont work. You use `self`. Try using a lambda: `self.Button = tk.Button(self.Main_frame, text='Enter', bg='green', command=lambda sheet: self.Longin(sheet))`

Answer (score 1):

Methods are bound to `self` when looked up on it. When decorating a method, the resulting *decorated method* is looked up on `self`, not the underlying method. You need to explicitly pass on the `self` parameter.

```
def search_func(sheetname):
  def insider(function):
      def wraper(self):  # the decorated method receives self...
          file = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\khisr\OneDrive\Documents\TestPage.xlsx")
          currnet_sheet = file[sheetname]
          function(self, currnet_sheet)  # ...and should pass it on
      return wraper
  return insider
```

Note that if you want to support not just regular methods, you must (partially) replicate the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors).

```
def search_func(sheetname):
  def insider(function):
      def wrapper(self):  # the decorated method receives self...
          file = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\khisr\OneDrive\Documents\TestPage.xlsx")
          currnet_sheet = file[sheetname]
          function.__get__(self, type(self))(currnet_sheet)  # ...and should pass it on
      return wraper
  return insider
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the suggestions but I seem to get this error now.                  


  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/khisr/OneDrive/Documents/PythonProjects/Dubai_Project/login.py", line 70, in wraper
    function.__get__(self, type(self))(currnet_sheet)
  File "C:/Users/khisr/OneDrive/Documents/PythonProjects/Dubai_Project/login.py", line 78, in Longin
    for i in range(1,current_sheet.max_row +1):
NameError: name 'current_sheet' is not defined

Comment: @user3064089 That looks like another problem. It is not related to the code and question here.

Comment: It complains about that it doesn't find the "current_sheet' " but as you can see in the code that is passed to the function.

Comment: @user3064089: you mean that `currnet_sheet`? Python is sensitive to typos in variable names. (Like, practically if not definitely all other programming languages.)